# how to sort data on the basis of count field in data array?

Tags: javascript

```
function getFrequency(str){
    var sorted = str.split("").sort();
    var data = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <sorted.length; i++){
        var last = data[data.length - 1]
        if(last && last.character === sorted[i]) last.count++;
        else data.push({character : sorted[i], count: 1});
    }

    return data;
}
```

it returns an array that consists of characters and their count. I want to arrange these in descending order of count. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the `data` array and use the property `count` for taking the delta as return value.

```
data.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
```

```js
function getFrequency(str){
    var sorted = str.split("").sort(),
        data = [],
        i,
        last;

    for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
        last = data[data.length - 1];
        if (last && last.character === sorted[i]) {
            last.count++;
        } else {
            data.push({ character: sorted[i], count: 1 });
        }
    }
    return data.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
}

console.log(getFrequency('zzzwwwwwabcdabaa'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort `data` based on `count` prop.

```js
function getFrequency(str){
    var sorted = str.split("").sort();
    var data = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <sorted.length; i++){
        var last = data[data.length - 1]
        if(last && last.character === sorted[i]) last.count++;
        else data.push({character : sorted[i], count: 1});
    }
    
    data = data.sort(function(a,b){
         return b.count - a.count
    });

    return data;
}

console.log(  getFrequency('aaaabddyww') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce()` to create an object for each character and add it to an array.

```js
function getFrequency(str) {
  var chars = str.split("");
  return chars.reduce((a, c) => {
    var f = a.find(e => e.character === c);
    if (f) f.count++;
    else a.push({
      character: c,
      count: 1
    });
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getFrequency('zzzwwwwwabcdabaa'))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) the string into an object of characters and counts. Convert to an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), then sort by `b.count - a.count`:

```js
function getFrequency(str) {
  return Object.values(str.split('')
    .reduce(function(r, c) {
      r[c] = r[c] || { character: c, count: 0 };
      r[c].count += 1;
      return r;
    }, Object.create(null))
  ).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
  });
}

console.log(getFrequency('who let the dogs out who who'));
```